# Qual è il significato di "sbragare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *La nascita del giullare* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> E poi corri nella piazza! 
>   Giullare sarai! Il padrone **sbragherà**, soldati, preti, 
>   notai sbiancheranno scoprendosi nudi come vermi!

Ho cercato il verbo "sbragare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho saputo trovare niente che abbia senso in questo contesto. Quindi, sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "il padrone sbragherà" nel passaggio sopra citato?

Answer (score 1):

Nel significato regionale di Treccani:

> In senso fig., nella forma rifl., assumere e mantenere un
>   atteggiamento trascurato, scomposto, sguaiato; determinando, sbracarsi
>   dalle risa, dal ridere, ridere a crepapelle, non poterne più dal
>   ridere.

Nel contesto da te citato ha il significato di arrabbiarsi, esagerare e andare su tutte le furie.